# Why are predefined unit file names in GNAT only 8 characters?

Tags: compiler-construction, runtime, naming-conventions, ada, gnat

I'm building a runtime for the Arduino Due, based on [this work by Brent Seidel](https://github.com/AdaCore/bb-runtimes/pull/15). The board uses an Atmel SAM3X8E processor, which as you might notice is a seven-letter name. Brent makes this note in the file [`a-sam3x8.ads`](https://github.com/AdaCore/bb-runtimes/blob/bf75bdddb1bb1437dd38fdacc4d1ad8212fa67c8/arm/sam/s-sam3x8.ads#L37):

```
--  This package should be called "System.Sam3x8e", but after lots of testing,
--  it seems that for some reason it just wouldn't find the package.  Calling
--  the package "System.Sam3x8" does work.
```

Indeed, after my own testing, I was not able to build the runtime with the "proper" name. Upon closer inspection, I noticed that all predefined files in GNAT and other BSPs seem to be exactly six letters long, plus the prefix as described in the [GNAT documentation on file naming rules](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/the_gnat_compilation_model.html#file-naming-rules). There is also some info there about `gnatkr` and "krunching" filenames to be a certain number of characters, and even an example of a predefined unit being krunched to 8 characters. However, I can't find any explanation as to **why** predefined units are shortened.

I suppose to fix this particular case I could name the package `System.SAM3X8E` and then krunch it or add `pragma Source_File_Name`, but I'd really rather just have descriptive filenames. In fact, I'd like it if I could rename *all* the predefined files to use their full names. I know they'd get long, but I'd rather have a long, descriptive names than a six-letter alphanumeric mess.

Comment: See [*8.3 filename*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename).

Comment: Interesting. So I guess when Ada first came out in '83 it was necessary, or at least enforced to ensure portability. And now it's kept that way for backwards compatibility.

Comment: GNAT came out later, around 1995 (with Ada 95...), but there was still DOS in the game - or Windows versions on top of DOS.

Comment: Thanks for the info, everyone. If someone wants to post an answer with this info I'll accept it as a best answer. Also thanks @Zerte for the edits for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54976045/why-are-predefined-unit-file-names-in-gnat-only-8-characters#comment96711348_54976045), this limitation is an accommodation for [8.3 filenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename), comprised of no more than eight characters and an optional extension. As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54976045/why-are-predefined-unit-file-names-in-gnat-only-8-characters#comment96713750_54976045) by @Zerte, GNAT came out ca. 1995 with the advent of Ada 95, a time when DOS was still popular and Windows ran atop DOS. Moreover, all file systems have name [length limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits), while descriptive package names and hierarchy depth don't. Implementations vary in how they accommodate the latter, but GNAT uses the file system.

Note that `gnatkr` simply transforms the package name to a file name that meets [*file naming rules*](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/the_gnat_compilation_model.html#file-naming-rules) cited in your question.

```
$ gnatkr System.Sam3x8e.adb
s-sam3x8.adb
```

It should be possible to have a package named `System.Sam3x8e` in a file named `s-sam3x8.ads`

```
package System.Sam3x8e is…
```

This would allow other compilation units to reference the full name in a context clause:

```
with System.Sam3x8e;
```

Comment: Thanks. For the record, rather than using `gnatkr` I used `pragma Source_File_Name` in `gnat.adc` to achieve the same result.